# lotto.php (I'm struggling with random numbers into "ticket")

Tags: php, html, arrays, post

I'm lost. I'm struggling with random numbers for my lotto.php. The first is going to my HTML:

```
<textarea name="ticket" rows="20" cols="20"></textarea>
```

How to take "ticket" to standard php format?

```
// Set the min/max
$numbers = array_fill(1,47,0);
// array-slice
$numbers = range(1, 47);
shuffle($numbers);
$numbers = array_slice($numbers, 0, 6);
print_r($numbers);
```

Also, I must have $_POST too.

Comment: My project has 5 random numbers (1-47) AND 1 mega number (1-40). How do I sort five numbers with a mega number? Also, I'm not understanding this: <textarea name="ticket" rows="20" cols="20"><?php echo $lottonum;</textarea>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) of PHP

```
<?php
$numbers = array_fill(1,47,0);
// array-slice
$numbers = range(1, 47);
shuffle($numbers);
$numbers = array_slice($numbers, 0, 6);
//print_r($numbers);
$lottonum = implode(" ", $numbers); // Space as seperator
echo $lottonum;
```

**OUTPUT :**

> 45 24 6 25 17 28

Comment: What about my "ticket" textarea? It's above my numbers, it's not in it.

Comment: You need add the variable inside it , Something like `<textarea name="ticket" rows="20" cols="20"><?php echo $lottonum;</textarea>`

Comment: My project has 5 random numbers (1-47) AND 1 mega number (1-40). How do I sort five numbers with a mega number? Also, I'm not understanding this: <textarea name="ticket" rows="20" cols="20"><?php echo $lottonum;</textarea>